# How to return something else after takeUntil in a nestjs interceptor

Tags: rxjs, nestjs

I'd like to return a different status code after the request close event inside an interceptor. Right now the following code will return status 200. Where should I throw an exception in this case?

```js
import { fromEvent, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class RequestCloseInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    return next.handle().pipe(takeUntil(fromEvent(request, 'close')));
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What status code are you attempting to return?

Comment: I found 499 but this is non-standard. Not sure if there's a more suitable one.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you can change the status code by calling status() on the HttpResponseContext

```
import { fromEvent, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class RequestCloseInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const response = context.switchToHttp().getResponse().status(201); // or any code you like
    return next.handle().pipe(takeUntil(fromEvent(request, 'close')));
  }
}
```

I'm unable to find documentation for this, but here is a related PR:

https://github.com/nestjs/nest/pull/1901/commits/922bbc3e574ebb7694514baa097e54913dceaf99#

Comment: Realized this solution will modify all the response' status code even if the request close event is not triggered, but I want it to change only when this specific event happens.

Comment: Ok i realized I can use do this  fromEvent(request, 'close').pipe(
            tap(() => context.switchToHttp().getResponse().status(499)),
          ) and the problem is solved. Not sure this is the best way

Comment: It doesn't appear to be implemented anywhere or registered with the http-status enums. https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/common/enums/http-status.enum.ts . The most you could do is create your own error class implementation that returns 499

Comment: I bet if you follow this example for another HttpException you could write your own Exception class that returns 499. https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/packages/common/exceptions/bad-request.exception.ts